# Where in iOS TimeValue symbol already used?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create class TimeValue with base class NSObject but getting compile error: `Redefinition of 'TimeValue' as different kind of symbol`. I was thinking that all iOS identifiers have some kind of prefix like NS, UI, etc.

Comment: It's declared in MacTypes.h as a typedef of `SInt32`

Comment: @dan ok, thank you. Please add your comment as answer.